# Remove items with sort and limit in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I can remove newest 10 items in mysql using my next sql statement.

```
DELETE FROM `mytable` order by id desc limit 10
```

Is it possible to do the same in Mongodb using sort and limit?

I know how to find last 10 items

```
db.collection.find({}).sort("id", -1).limit(10)
```

but I'm not sure how delete items in one step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in two steps like this:

```
const ids = db.collection.find({})
                     .sort("id", -1)
                     .limit(10)
                     .toArray()
                     .map(ele => ele._id);

db.collection.remove({_id: {$in: ids}})
```